# Where is the GetCustomAttributes method of the ActionDescriptor with Swashbuckle in asp.net core 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

Old ASP.NET Web API 2:

```
apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>();
```

`apiDescription` is a parameter from the interface `IOperationFilter` method

```
public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
```

ASP.NET Core 6 Web API (does not work):

```
public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    

context.ApiDescription.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>());
```

Where did they hide the `GetCustomAttributes` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `OperationFilterContext.MethodInfo`:

```cs
context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<MyCustomAttribute>();
```